# Count number of columns with INPUT for each row

Tags: r

probably a really basic question but I cannot figure it out.
Assume the following test code:

```
test1 = tibble::tribble(
  ~name1,      ~name2, ~name3, ~name4, ~name5,
  "B565",      "F226",     NA,     NA,     NA,
  "W342", "DUPLICATE",     NA,     NA,     NA,
  "H452",      "K632", "L553", "DUPLICATE", "R551"
)
Created on 2021-06-08 by the reprex package (v2.0.0)
```

No I simply want to count for every row how many entries I have without the NAs and put the result in a new column `test1$itemno`

Thought rowSum would be a good idea.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr` without `rowwise` you may do something like this

```r
library(dplyr)

test1 %>% mutate(item_count = rowSums(cur_data() != ''))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   name1 name2     name3  name4       name5  item_count
#>   <chr> <chr>     <chr>  <chr>       <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1 B565  F226      ""     ""          ""              2
#> 2 W342  DUPLICATE ""     ""          ""              2
#> 3 H452  K632      "L553" "DUPLICATE" "R551"          5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

For revised data

```
test1 %>% mutate(item_count = rowSums(!is.na(cur_data())))

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  name1 name2     name3 name4     name5 item_count
  <chr> <chr>     <chr> <chr>     <chr>      <dbl>
1 B565  F226      NA    NA        NA             2
2 W342  DUPLICATE NA    NA        NA             2
3 H452  K632      L553  DUPLICATE R551           5
```

Comment: thanks for your answer for the empty string this worked fine. Now I updated the code and put NA instead of an empty string but if I Replace  !='' to !=NA the counting does not work anymore.

Comment: @MaxH. That's not a correct way to deal with NAs.  Use is.na() or! is.na() instead

Answer (score 0):

My solution is as follows:

```r
total = c()
for(i in 1:length(test1$name1)){ 
    total = c(total, sum(test1[i,] != ""))
}
test1$itemno = total

test1
```

Outputs

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  name1 name2     name3  name4       name5      itemno
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>  <chr>       <chr>      <int>
1 B565  F226      ""     ""          ""             2
2 W342  DUPLICATE ""     ""          ""             2
3 H452  K632      "L553" "DUPLICATE" "R551"         5
```

**Note**: You can probably find a more elegant solution using a function in the [apply](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-tutorial-apply-family) family.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

test1 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(itemno = sum(!c_across() == ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
test1$item_count <-  rowSums(test1 != ''))
```